# Google will Requrie all publisher serving ads to EEA and UK users GDPR

Tags: java, android, admob

I recently opened AdMob and received this message:

> Later this year, Google will require all publishers serving ads to EEA and UK users to use a Google-certified Consent Management Platform (CMP). You can use any Google-certified CMP for this purpose, including Google's own consent management solution. If you are interested in using Google's consent management solution, start by setting up your GDPR message and implementing the UMP SDK.

Should we update all applications?

Comment: ffs will google ever stop annoying us with stupid bs every week

Comment: If you have users in EEA or UK, just add UMP implementation to those apps. Select them from the AdMob's dashboard & select the apps.

Comment: implement code in app or only make changes in admob?

Comment: You need to create a GDPR message on AdMob dashboard & implement UMP sdk in the app.

Comment: @Darshan After creating GDPR message on AdMob what code need to write in iOS and as well in android?

Comment: Does this mean we should no longer show ads to those who refuse consent? Can I prevent them from using my apps if they reject it?

Comment: @JP711 If they don't give you the consent, you can't show them personalized ads. Non-personalized ads can be shown. You just need to ask them at first launch, what they want to see...